# Custom directive

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-directives

The [documentation for custom directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Dynamic-Directive-Arguments) demonstrates using a dynamic argument and a value together:

> Directive arguments can be dynamic. For example, in `v-mydirective:[argument]="value"`, the argument can be updated based on data properties in our component instance! This makes our custom directives flexible for use throughout our application.

If `"value"` doesn't contain a space, it works fine. But adding a space to the value (e.g. `v-mydirective:[argument]="some value"`) causes Nuxt to choke:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    some value

  Raw expression: v-mydirective:[argument]="some value"
```

What is the problem, and how do I resolve it so that I can use a string with a space as the value to the custom directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

This happens because when we pass `value` with spaces, the expression is evaluated by vuejs and it tries to find the `data` options with property `some` & `value`. But as none exists with those property names, hence we get the mentioned error.

A simple example to explain this is when we pass `value` as:

```
v-mydirective:[argument]="2"
```

and if we do `console.log` inside `bind` function:

```
console.log(binding.value)
```

You will see the output displayed as `2`. But, if we pass `value` as:

```
v-mydirective:[argument]="2 + 2"
```

and if we do `console.log` inside `bind` function, interestingly the output displayed this time is `4` instead of `2 + 2`

---

### Solutions:

There are two possible solutions for this:

**Solution #1:**

You can simply wrap `some value` in single quotes and pass it as a string like:

```
v-mydirective:[argument]="'some value'"
```

This way the expression will be directly evaluated as string instead.

**Demo:**

```js
Vue.directive('pin', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log(binding.value)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#dynamicexample',
  data: function () {
    return {
      direction: 'left',
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#dynamicexample {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #304455;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamicexample">
  <p v-pin:[direction]="'some value'">I am pinned onto the page at 200px to the left.</p>
</div>
```

**Solution #2:**

You can also create a separate `data` option for it like:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    myValue: 'some value'
  }
}
```

and then you can use it in directive like:

```
v-mydirective:[argument]="myValue"
```

**Demo:**

```js
Vue.directive('pin', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log(binding.value)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#dynamicexample',
  data: function () {
    return {
      direction: 'left',
      myValue: 'some value'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#dynamicexample {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #304455;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamicexample">
  <p v-pin:[direction]="myValue">I am pinned onto the page at 200px to the left.</p>
</div>
```